# Android how to use an application Context among models?

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android project, it has two modules one is for business another is for logic. Like this:

```
MyProject
  > My-app-module
  > My-logic-app-module
     > settings
        >SetNetworkManager.java
```

There are many places call a method `method1` from `SetNetworkManager.java`  and works well.

But now i need to store a value in `sharedPreferences` if so i have to use a `Context` in `method1`. How can i get Context?

So how can i use **My-app-moudle** application context in  **My-logic-app-moudle** ?

My idea is use a **My-app-module** Application context but just not sure how or if possible?

If use `Context` as a parameter in `method1`, i have to change about 100 places, it obviously not a good idea.

Comment: You could pass context as a constructor argument for `SetNetworkManager` and store it in a private variable.

Comment: But i have to change every SetNetworkManager() to SetNetworkManager(context) , right?

Comment: Yes. It's a single find & replace call, takes you about a minute.

Comment: `CTRL+SHIFT+R` in android studio

Comment: Actually it's not just F&R. Some places also not activity class etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use Singleton Pattern for SetNetworkManager.java and pass context argument
like SetNetworkManager.getInstance(this).method1();

EDIT:

You can use SharePref singleton and you don't need change SetNetworkManager constructor.
Check my github: 
https://github.com/dockusan/android-base-framework/blob/master/AndroidBaseFramework/app/src/main/java/dockusan/com/androidbaseframework/BaseApplication.java

Just call:

```
SharedPrefUtils.putInt("key",1);
```

Comment: Avoid using Singleton pattern this way, your code will become unmantainableo over time.